# Issue while running interactive GUI with xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I have built a GUI (with PyQt5) which allow me to read an CSV, made some basic actions and send it to Excel.

Then, I integrated this GUI into Excel using xlwings but I have a problem. When I am using the GUI, I can't manipulate the data in Excel. I assume it's because my macro is still running.

Is there a way to run my GUI without loosing control of Excel ?

```
def Main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and in Excel :

```
Sub GUI()
    RunPython ("import UImainwindow; UImainwindow.Main())
End sub
```

Comment: it very hard to follow what exactly you did when you say "Integrated this GUI into Excel". Can you add some more details or pseudo code? Also, are you on windows or mac?

Comment: I run my GUI like any other function. I'm on Windows.

Comment: Hi. I finaly play with the "WaitOnReturn" argument  of WScript.Shell. I add an optional argument on ExecuteWindows (Optional WaitOnReturnBool As Boolean) and on other optional argument on RunPython (Optional ByVal WaitOnReturnBool As Boolean). But when I try to run RunPython function like this RunPython(StringCommand, False) I got a syntax error. I'm close !

Comment: nb : for myself, dont put braket on excel function with multiple argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I got a solution.

I modify the ExecuteWindows sub to add an optional argument like this :

```
Sub ExecuteWindows(IsFrozen As Boolean, PythonCommand As String, PYTHON_WIN As String, LOG_FILE As String, SHOW_LOG As Boolean, Optional PYTHONPATH As String, Optional WaitOnReturnBool As Boolean)
```

then I modify RunPython function like this

```
Public Function RunPython(PythonCommand As String, Optional ByVal WaitOnReturnBool As Boolean = True)
```

and

```
ExecuteWindows False, PythonCommand, PYTHON_WIN, LOG_FILE, SHOW_LOG, PYTHONPATH, WaitOnReturnBool
```

And finaly call the RunPython function with two argument

```
RunPython command, WaitOnReturnBool
```

I had to use wb=xw.Workbook.active() instead of wb=xw.Workbook.caller() in my script but it works.
That's allowed me to run an extern GUI without loosing control of Excel.

Comment: hello Coolpix I found it is so cool!I want to.study the example.Will you please pack the example and email to happyzhong0618@gmail.com?